# T-SQL if statement error

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql, if-statement

i'm trying to execute the following SQL 2008 code it says there is a problem near "=" and "else"... i cant understand what is wrong with the code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.LoginEmp @username NVARCHAR(10),
                             @password NVARCHAR(10),
                             @confirm  INT output,
                             @emp_name NVARCHAR(50) output,
                             @emp_id   BIGINT output
AS
    IF EXISTS (SELECT @emp_id = emp_id,
                      @emp_name = emp_name_ara
               FROM   Employee
               WHERE  ( emp_username LIKE @username
                        AND emp_password LIKE @password ))
      BEGIN
          SET @confirm=1

          INSERT INTO EmployeeLog
                      (log_emp_id,
                       log_act_id,
                       log_date,
                       log_data)
          VALUES      (@emp_id,
                       1,
                       GETDATE(),
                       -1)
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
          SET @confirm=0
      END

    RETURN
```

Comment: if the syntax is like in oracle, there is missing "then" and "endif"

Comment: @MartinSmith Is there any tool to format the SQL code like above ? If yes can you pls provide the link.

Comment: You won't be able to assign a variable inside the `EXISTS(SELECT`. @Santosh I use SQL Pretty Printer. An online version is here http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm

Comment: On a side note, shouldn't username an password tests use = instead if LIKE ?

Comment: @desperateCoder no its in sql server 2008

Comment: @MartinSmith Why i cant assign a value to a variable ito IF EXISTS ?

Comment: @MarcelloRomani My friend its a nvarchar field so its better if i use LIKE operator

Comment: @iceDragon - A statement that assigns to variables does not return any result set so it doesn't make sense inside an `EXISTS`

Comment: IMHO authenticating via LIKE comparison is a MAJOR security hole. Plus, I think SQL Server has an Unicode-aware = operator http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189863.aspx

Comment: @MarcelloRomani is correct. If you know a username then you could just enter `%` as the password to authenticate with `LIKE`. It should use `=` (and also passwords should be hashed anyway in most cases)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to assign to the output parameters inside the `EXISTS` do the assignment then check `@@rowcount` to see if any matching row(s) were found.

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.LoginEmp @username NVARCHAR(10),
                             @password NVARCHAR(10),
                             @confirm  INT output,
                             @emp_name NVARCHAR(50) output,
                             @emp_id   BIGINT output
AS
    SELECT @emp_id = emp_id,
           @emp_name = emp_name_ara
    FROM   Employee
    WHERE  ( emp_username = @username
             AND emp_password = @password )

    IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1
      BEGIN
          SET @confirm=1

          INSERT INTO EmployeeLog
                      (log_emp_id,
                       log_act_id,
                       log_date,
                       log_data)
          VALUES      (@emp_id,
                       1,
                       GETDATE(),
                       -1)
      END
    ELSE
      BEGIN
          SET @confirm=0
      END
```

Comment: @iceDragon - You may well want to use `IF @@ROWCOUNT = 1` instead of `IF @@ROWCOUNT > 0` I just used the second one to preserve as far as possible what the original semantics with `EXISTS` would have been.

Answer (score 1):

Exists operator checks if any row present in resultset returned by query.
In your example it's just assigning values to variable.
For more reference please check this link : [Assigning a variable inside an IF EXISTS clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598740/assigning-a-variable-inside-an-if-exists-clause)

Answer (score 0):

Can you move `IF EXISTS` after `BEGIN`

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE dbo.LoginEmp
@username nvarchar(10),
@password nvarchar(10),
@confirm int output,
@emp_name nvarchar(50) output,
@emp_id bigint output
AS 
Begin
if exists (SELECT emp_id, emp_name_ara FROM Employee WHERE        (emp_username LIKE @username AND emp_password LIKE @password)) begin
  // Here Retrieve the Data into Variable again. Like You did Above Before.
set @confirm=1

INSERT INTO EmployeeLog (log_emp_id,log_act_id,log_date,log_data) VALUES (@emp_id,1,GETDATE(),-1)

end
else begin

set @confirm=0
end 
end
RETURN
```

Comment: it doesn't affect the result :S

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
SELECT @emp_id = emp_id,
                      @emp_name = emp_name_ara
```

to

```
SELECT emp_id, emp_name_ara
```

Append **@emp_id** and  **@emp_name** variables to WHERE clause

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT  emp_id, emp_name_ara
               FROM   Employee
               WHERE  ( emp_username LIKE @username
                        AND emp_password LIKE @password AND emp_id=@emp_id AND emp_name_ara = @emp_name  ))
```

Comment: but i need to assign those values to the output variables

Comment: i am not using the variables to test a value, i need a return value through them