# SQL Server stored procedure compile error

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Stored procedure is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountUtily
    @domain varchar(50),
    @count int,
    @totalCount int OUT
AS 
BEGIN   
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @totalCount=0

    IF (EXISTS (SELECT @totalCount = count 
                FROM FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount 
                WHERE domain = @domain))
    BEGIN
        SET @totalCount = @totalCount + @count

        UPDATE FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount 
        SET count = @totalCount 
        WHERE domain = @domain
    END
    ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount (domain, count) 
        VALUES (@domain, @count)
    END
END
```

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near '='. Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'ELSE'.

Comment: @Ajmot, that's a `MySQL` syntax. In `SQL Server` there is no `FROM` clause in `UPDATE` statement.

Comment: I don't think you can select @totalCount = count within the Exists function.
Check out this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598740/assigning-a-variable-inside-an-if-exists-clause

Comment: @Rahul yes, i messed up . my bad. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [**EXISTS**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx)

> Specifies a subquery to test for the existence of rows. it Returns
> `TRUE` if a subquery contains any rows,it accept `restricted SELECT statement`, The `INTO` keyword is not allowed.
>
> the problem here is you can't set the value inside the Exists.

Try

```
alter PROCEDURE CountUtily
    @domain varchar(50),
    @count int,
    @totalCount int OUT
AS BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    SET @totalCount=0;

    IF (EXISTS (SELECT [count] FROM FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount WHERE domain=@domain))
    begin
        SELECT @totalCount=[count] FROM FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount WHERE domain=@domain
        UPDATE FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount SET count=@totalCount WHERE domain=@domain
    end
    ELSE
    begin
        INSERT INTO FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount (domain, count) VALUES (@domain, @count)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

your Select @totalCount = count does not return a bool. Try setting @totalCount before the if evaluates and eval the count in the if

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountUtily
@domain varchar(50),
@count int,
@totalCount int OUT
AS BEGIN    
SET NOCOUNT ON
SET @totalCount=0

SELECT  @totalCount=count FROM FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount WHERE 

IF (@totalCount > 0)
begin
    SET @totalCount=@totalCount+@count
    UPDATE FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount SET count=@totalCount WHERE domain=@domain
end
ELSE
begin
    INSERT INTO FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount (domain, count) VALUES (@domain, @count)
end
end
```

Comment: Problem is @totalCount can be >=0 .. I cant use it into if.. what should I do?

Comment: I am not able to follow what you are attempting to do with your original exists() statement. Do you mean to use "@@ROWCOUNT"?

Comment: yes,`if exists ()`was the main issue here, which accept the `restricted sub query` only.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing `;` to mark the end of the statement here. Again, `count` is a reserve word and so escape it using `[]`. Your posted procedure can be modified to

```
CREATE PROCEDURE CountUtily(
    @domain varchar(50),
    @count int,
    @totalCount int OUT)
AS BEGIN    
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET @totalCount=0;
    SELECT  @totalCount=[count] FROM FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount WHERE domain=@domain;
    IF (@totalCount IS NOT NULL)
    begin
        SET @totalCount=@totalCount+@count;
        UPDATE FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount SET [count]=@totalCount WHERE domain=@domain;
    end
    ELSE
        INSERT INTO FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount (domain, [count]) VALUES (@domain, @count);
end
```

Comment: Its compiled. But the when I am executing using C# code, the INSERT is not working. Its not inserting any row but also not returning any error.

Comment: @Arnab, you have a `if..else` in procedure. So check probably the update is taking place instead of insert.

Answer (score 0):

You've made this query too complicated with the count and totalcount variables; all of which you do not need.

So, you want to update the "count" field of your "FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount" when the field "domain" matches a parameter @domain; or you want to Insert it if it doesn't exist.

OK, let's do that using @@RowCount.

```
    UPDATE FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount SET [count] = ([count]+@count) where [domain] = @domain
If (@@ROWCOUNT > 0)
BEGIN
    return 1 --updated : or return whatever you need to show it updated
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO FormFillerAuto2_DomainCount ([domain], [count]) VALUES (@domain, @count)
    return 2 --inserted : or return whatever you need to show it inserted
END
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your update is a bit screw up..  It should be
UPDATE TABLENAME
SET COLUMNNAME = VALUE
WHERE CONDITION

Readability will help understand and maintain code.