# Unable to store value in a variable

Tags: sql-server

```
DECLARE @systemUnitGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
DECLARE @adminID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER = '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

IF EXISTS(
       SELECT @systemUnitGuid = UR_UN_GUID_To
       FROM Un_Unit
       INNER JOIN UR_UnitRelation ON UR_UN_GUID_To = UN_GUID
                                  AND UR_CLSID = '5514c560-12ec-11de-8c30-0800200c9a66'
       WHERE UR_UN_GUID_From = '8dbc36fc-f2f1-4ed9-a5b0-025857436828')
BEGIN
    IF @guidId = @systemUnitGuid
    BEGIN
        SELECT UN_GUID
        FROM Un_Unit
        INNER JOIN UR_UnitRelation ON UR_UN_GUID_From = UN_GUID
                                   AND UR_CLSID = '710b45c3-8a23-4cc3-a684-8eed6ddc1fb7'
        WHERE UR_UN_GUID_To = @guidId
    END
```

I get the following error

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 13
>   Incorrect syntax near '='.

Please suggest

Comment: You are missing an `END` to finish the outer block. Not sure if that will fullysolve the issue but it will help.

Comment: where `@guidId` is declared and what is it's type?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) You need to declare the @guidId variable

2) You cannot assign value to variable inside the EXISTS.

3) Try like this:

```
DECLARE @systemUnitGuid UNIQUEIDENTIFIER='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000' 
DECLARE @adminID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'
DECLARE @guidId UNIQUEIDENTIFIER='00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000'

SET @systemUnitGuid = (
        SELECT UR_UN_GUID_To
        FROM   Un_Unit
               INNER JOIN UR_UnitRelation
                    ON  UR_UN_GUID_To = UN_GUID
                        AND UR_CLSID     = '5514c560-12ec-11de-8c30-0800200c9a66'
        WHERE  UR_UN_GUID_From           = '8dbc36fc-f2f1-4ed9-a5b0-025857436828'
    )

IF (@systemUnitGuid =  @guidId)
BEGIN
    SELECT UN_GUID
    FROM   Un_Unit
            INNER JOIN UR_UnitRelation
                ON  UR_UN_GUID_From = UN_GUID
                    AND UR_CLSID     = '710b45c3-8a23-4cc3-a684-8eed6ddc1fb7'
    WHERE  UR_UN_GUID_To             = @guidId
END
```

**NOTE:-** *If @guid is an input parameter and you are using this inside a function or stored procedure then you can remove the declaration part of @guid variable.*

Answer (score 0):

You are setting a variable in an exists clause, you cannot do this.
See [Assigning a variable inside an IF EXISTS clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598740/assigning-a-variable-inside-an-if-exists-clause) for possible workarounds.