# syntax error in SELECT statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

With my limited SQL knowledge, I'm unable to figure this out. What's wrong with the following:

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Name varchar(40)

WHILE EXISTS
        (
        SELECT TOP 1 @Name = Name, @Id=ID FROM MyTable c WHERE <CONDITION>
        )
BEGIN
    SOME MORE SQL using @Id and @Name
END
```

I get a syntax error near `@Name = Name`

### EDIT

To add more context to the problem, I have two tables named `Category (ID, Name, ParentID)` and `Account(ID, Name, CategoryID)`.

There are 3 levels of `Categories`.

1. Root
2. Category
3. SubCategory

This is achieved using a recursive relation (`ParentID` > `CategoryID`). Problem to solve is that if there are any `Accounts` that belongs to a Category X (level 2), we must

1. Create a SubCategory Y (level 3) with the same name as X
2. Make Y a child of that X
3. Move all Accounts from X to Y

Here is the original script I have written:

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Name varchar(40)

WHILE EXISTS(
        SELECT TOP 1 @Name=Name, @Id=CategoryID FROM Category c WHERE 
        ParentID = (SELECT TOP 1 CategoryID FROM Category WHERE Name = 'Root') AND
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE CategoryID = c.CategoryID) > 0
        )
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO Category(Name, ParentID) VALUES(@Name, @Id)
    UPDATE Account SET CategoryID = @@IDENTITY WHERE CategoryID = @Id  
END
```

Comment: @Ian: `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

Comment: What is the structure of `MyTable`?

Comment: SELECT TOP 1 is expecting the next thing to be a column name, but you're providing an assignment expression. (Id risk suggesting, even though i might be very wrong)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: `ID int, Name varchar(40), ParentID int`

Comment: @Felype: I know for sure that `SELECT @X = ColName FROM TableName` syntax works.

Comment: but it doesn't work as a subquery; @Felype is correct.

Comment: What is there in *SOME MORE SQL ...*? This smells like *procedural approach*. Might be an [XY-Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I'm quite sure, that there'll be a *set-based* approach too...

Comment: The syntax is invalid since you are attempting to assign the values and read them. See here for a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8598740/assigning-a-variable-inside-an-if-exists-clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `CURSOR` loop:

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Mytable(ID, Name) VALUES (1,10),(2,20);

DECLARE @Id int;
DECLARE @Name varchar(40);

DECLARE cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR SELECT Name,ID FROM MyTable c WHERE 1=1;

OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Id, @Name;

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
   SELECT @Id,@Name;   

   FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Id, @Name;
END;

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](http://rextester.com/WMT90885)**</kbd>

Please note that `TOP 1` without explicit `ORDER BY` may produce different results between executions.

---

[`EXISTS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336.aspx):

> EXISTS subquery

Note that `SELECT @ID = id, @Name = Name` is not subquery but assignment.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(ID INT, Name VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO Mytable(Id, Name) VALUES (1,10),(2,20);

DECLARE @Id int;
DECLARE @Name varchar(40);

SELECT 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT @id = id FROM Mytable);  -- assignment
-- Incorrect syntax near '='.

SELECT 1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT id FROM Mytable);        -- subquery
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo 2`](http://rextester.com/XDFFU90461)**</kbd>

Comment: This is a good solution to the immediate problem; the larger question is why does the OP need to use a loop to begin with.  There are always situations, but they should be rare.

Comment: Thanks for the effort and providing an actual solution. @StuartAinsworth: I have added more detail to the question. Maybe that helps u to suggest an even better solution?

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your cursor approach did it for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to use `While`, you can use if condition instead of `while` like this - `

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Name varchar(40)

SELECT TOP 1 @Name = Name, @Id=ID FROM MyTable c WHERE <CONDITION>

-- Now Check for @Name and @ID
IF ISNULL(@Name, '') <> '' AND ISNULL(@Id, 0) <> 0
BEGIN
      SOME MORE SQL using @Id and @Name
END
```

**EDITED**

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM Category c 
            WHERE ParentID = (SELECT TOP 1 CategoryID FROM Category WHERE Name = 'Root')  
            AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE CategoryID = c.CategoryID) > 0
        )
BEGIN

     SELECT TOP 1 @Name=Name, @Id=CategoryID FROM Category c 
        WHERE ParentID = (SELECT TOP 1 CategoryID FROM Category WHERE Name = 'Root') 
        AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE CategoryID = c.CategoryID) > 0

    INSERT INTO Category(Name, ParentID) 
      VALUES(@Name, @Id)

    SET @CategoryID = SCOPE_IDENTITY()

    UPDATE Account SET CategoryID = @CategoryID WHERE CategoryID = @Id  

END
```

Comment: @dotNET: See my Edited answer. Hope it help you.

Comment: How will this script fix it for ALL categories?

Answer (score 1):

[SELECT @local_variable (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187330.aspx)

> A SELECT statement that contains a variable assignment cannot be used
>   to also perform typical result set retrieval operations.

Here you use EXISTS to retrieve data so I guess you can't use assignment inside a subquery.

Try to implement equivalent WHILE TRUE loop with BREAK.

```
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @Name varchar(40)

WHILE (1=1)

BEGIN

SET @Name = NULL;
SET @id = NULL;

SELECT TOP 1 @Name=Name, @Id=CategoryID FROM Category c WHERE 
        ParentID = (SELECT TOP 1 CategoryID FROM Category WHERE Name = 'Root') 
         AND
        (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Account WHERE CategoryID = c.CategoryID) > 0
        );

    IF (@ID IS NULL) BREAK;

    INSERT INTO Category(Name, ParentID) VALUES(@Name, @Id);
    UPDATE Account SET CategoryID = @@IDENTITY WHERE CategoryID = @Id ; 
END
```

Comment: Very precise. Actually answers the question. What would be the correct line of action for me (see my edit)?

Comment: @dotNET I've added an equivalent WHILE TRUE loop. Please test it.

Comment: Nicely done. I like lad2025's answer too. Can't select more than one answer, but this one definitely deserves an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Use this for check record existence

```
WHILE EXISTS
    (
    SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable c WHERE <CONDITION>
    )
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @Name = Name, @Id=ID FROM MyTable c WHERE <CONDITION>

-- and do here what you want
END
```